# AVD Android Emulator - Failing to load

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My android virtual device not load. I am using API_27 with hardware GLES 2.0. It is running on vmware ubuntu 16.04. Ram size is 4gb.

Here is a paste bin of the logcat after it has been loading for 1 hour - https://pastebin.com/YYucCtKE. After around 1 hour it crashed.

**Event Log**

```
12/14/17
12:00 PM    Emulator: context mismatch in svga_sampler_view_destroy

12:00 PM    Emulator: VMware: vmw_ioctl_command error Invalid argument.

12:00 PM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

**Some Logcat Errors:**

```
Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1
```

-

```
12-14 10:52:20.828 1380-1383/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory
12-14 10:52:20.829 1380-1383/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/misc_ce/0: No such file or directory
12-14 10:52:20.840 1380-1383/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/media/0: No such file or directory
```

-

```
12-14 10:52:35.630 1522-1540/? E/vndksupport: Could not load /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found.
```

-

```
12-14 11:48:08.609 1424-1907/? E/EffectsConfig: Failed to parse /vendor/etc/audio_effects.xml: Tinyxml2 error (3): /vendor/etc/audio_effects.xml (null)
12-14 11:48:08.612 1424-1907/? E/EffectsFactoryConfigLoader: Failed to parse XML configuration file
12-14 11:48:08.637 1424-1907/? W/EffectsFactory: Failed to load XML effect configuration, fallback to .conf
```

-

```
12-14 15:14:01.090 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-14 15:14:01.198 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:8.1.0/OSM2.171116.002/4458339:userdebug/dev-keys'
12-14 15:14:01.199 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
12-14 15:14:01.210 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
12-14 15:14:01.240 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG: pid: 11676, tid: 11676, name: zygote  >>> zygote <<<
12-14 15:14:01.299 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
12-14 15:14:01.319 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'heap.cc:438] Check failed: region_space_mem_map != nullptr No region space mem map'
12-14 15:14:01.320 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00002d9c  ecx 00002d9c  edx 00000006
12-14 15:14:01.361 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     esi ad3d9000  edi 00002d9c
12-14 15:14:01.397 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
12-14 15:14:01.399 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     eip b1ca0ac4  ebp cb1f9ecb  esp bff54998  flags 00000286
12-14 15:14:01.610 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
12-14 15:14:01.678 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000ac4  [vdso:b1ca0000] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
12-14 15:14:01.681 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0001edf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
12-14 15:14:01.829 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0001f073  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
12-14 15:14:01.840 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0054d4eb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+603)
12-14 15:14:01.880 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0011fb23  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIPFvPKcENS_9allocatorIS5_EES4_EclEOS3_+35)
12-14 15:14:01.901 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0065f26b  /system/lib/libart.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1051)
12-14 15:14:01.917 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0027a97d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::Heap(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, double, double, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, art::InstructionSet, art::gc::CollectorType, art::gc::CollectorType, art::gc::space::LargeObjectSpaceType, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, unsig
12-14 15:14:01.918 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0055066d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime4InitEONS_18RuntimeArgumentMapE+10413)
12-14 15:14:01.919 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00554808  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Create(std::__1::vector<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, void const*>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, void const*>>> const&, bool)+184)
12-14 15:14:01.929 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0039ace7  /system/lib/libart.so (JNI_CreateJavaVM+647)
12-14 15:14:01.940 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 000044ae  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so (JNI_CreateJavaVM+46)
12-14 15:14:01.959 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00077d5d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::startVm(_JavaVM**, _JNIEnv**, bool)+7581)
12-14 15:14:01.960 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0007823b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+395)
12-14 15:14:01.969 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00001db2  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+1602)
12-14 15:14:01.970 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 000b69e4  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+100)
12-14 15:14:02.040 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 000016cd  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+80)
12-14 15:14:02.049 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 000016d8  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start+10)
12-14 15:14:02.060 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00000004  <unknown>
12-14 15:14:02.079 11719-11719/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 00020b97  <anonymous:bff37000>
12-14 15:14:08.048 11719-11719/? E/crash_dump32: unable to connect to activity manager: Connection refused
12-14 15:14:08.057 1574-1574/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoever made your emulator, did not build the vndk-sp-libs, which made the linker reject API calls. This is due to a split in the linker and in vendor/lib and system/lib in Android Oreo.
Surfaceflinger is not allowed to load the required graphics library, and so you get the endless crashing.

If you ran it from Android Studio, my guess is that updating the emulator version would solve it. If you built your own emulator/were provided a user built emulator - point them to that root cause.